# mixed-effect model in SAS

Tags: sas, mixed-models

I tried to conduct a mixed-effect model to test the interaction affection of time*treamtment on specific outcomes. However, I noticed that when I tried to control the variable "overall_pi" in the model as a covariate, the SAS output would give me a long list of iteration history instead of coefficient estimates (see pic).[image]

However, if I took out this covariate, SAS would give me all coefficients for all predictors. (see pic2)
[image]

I wonder why it doesn't give me the coefficient values if I added "overall_pi" to the model listed below. Thanks.

Codes are:

```
DATA Mixed1;
SET anova_analysis2023;
ARRAY A1{*} pit0 pdit2;
DO TMP = 1 to 2; 
    TMPV = VNAME(A1{TMP});
    AVAL = A1{TMP};
    OUTPUT;
END;RUN;


PROC MIXED DATA = Mixed1;
    CLASS ID TMP(ref="1") BRIGHT(ref="0") POC/*IF CATEGORICAL COVARIATES ADD HERE*/;
    MODEL AVAL = TMP|BRIGHT POC other_op_inlife_t0 aas_depend_t0 /*IF CONTINUOUS COVARIATES HERE*/ / S E1 E2;
    REPEATED TMP / SUBJECT = ID TYPE = UN RCORR;
    LSMEANS TMP TMP*BRIGHT / CL DIFFS;
    TITLE1 “Mixed Model (Interaction) between group (BRIGHT) and Time”;
RUN;
```